# Questions on C# Strings: Immutablility & Cloning

Tags: c#

i am reading Accelerated C# 2010. and have a few questions

**Question 1**

> Instances of String are immutable in
>   the sense that once you create them,
>   you cannot change them

how is that true. i have not used C# for sometime, plus i am just starting so i maybe wrong even in the syntax.

```
string str1 = "this is a string"; // i hope my syntax is right 
str1 = "this is a NEW string"; // i think i can do this right?
```

**Question 2**

> If you call  the ICloneable.Clone
>   method on a string, you get an
>   instance that points to the same
>   string data as the  source. In fact,
>   ICloneable.Clone simply returns a
>   reference to this

if this is true, it means that

```
string str1 = "string 1";
// i hope my syntax is right too. i am really not sure about this
string str2 = str1.Clone(); 
str2 = "modified string"; // will str1 be modified too?
```

Comment: The underlying reason for all of this is that `string` is a reference type designed to emulate value semantics through immutability.

Comment: @Steven: Exactly, and it works because `==` on strings in C# also simulates these value semantics (contrary to Java, where `if (userInput == "yes") ...` is a common beginner's mistake).

Comment: @Heinzi: Right. The default `==` would compare addresses, whereas `string` compares the actual characters. (Actually, it also checks addresses first, but only to see if they match and therefore the character-by-character comparison is unneeded.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string str1 = "this is a string"; // i hope my syntax is right 
str1 = "this is a NEW string"; // i think i can do this right?
```

Sure! `string` is a reference type (a *pointer*, if you want so see it like this), so in line 2, you are making variable `str1` point to a *different* (constant) string in memory. The original string is not changed, it's just not referenced any more.

```
string str1 = "string 1";
string str2 = str1.Clone(); // i hope my syntax is right too. i am really not sure about this
str2 = "modified string"; // will str1 be modified too?
```

No, because you didn't modify `"string 1"`. After line 2, it looked like this:

```
memory            "string 1"
                    ^    ^ 
                    |    |
stack             str1  str2
```

After line 3, it looks like this:

```
memory            "string 1"     "modified string"
                      ^              ^
                      |              |
stack                str1           str2
```

Comment: It is important to note that the reason why the references look like the diagram after calling the Clone() method is that because the Clone() method for string is implemented to return 'this'.  Normally one would expect Clone() to return a new instance with identical contents (but this achieves little for immutable types, so the optimisation for String is reasonable).

Comment: can i say when i (re)assign a string, i am always making it point to another string in memory. thus that will explain why even tho `str2` references the same point in memory as `str1`, when i reassign it, it do not modify `str1`?

Comment: @jiewmeng: Basically, yes. In general, if `a` is a reference type pointing to some memory location `A` and you write the statement `a = b`, this statement *never* modifies the content of `A`. Instead, you are making `a` point at the same memory location that `b` is currently pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

The consensus answer here is correct.

The string type is a reference type to an immutable string in memory.  A collection of all your strings is created in memory (aptly referred to as a string pool) that contain the strings you have created.  In question 1, your first statement creates a string in memory, and assigns str1 a reference to that string in the string pool.

When you do the following

```
str1 = "this is a NEW string";
```

you are actually adding a new string to the string pool (creating a new string transparently) then assigning str1 a reference to the new string.

Consider this, for example:

```
string str1 = "this is my old string";
str1 = "this is my NEW string"; 
str1 = "this is my old string";
```

In this scenario, only two strings are created in the string pool.  When you reach the third line in your code, the .NET platform checks the string pool, finds a match, and gives str1 a reference to the string in the string pool that already exists, rather than creating a duplicate.

To drive the point home, let's do this:

```
string str1 = "this is a string";
string str2 = "this is a string";
//both strings have a reference to the same string in memory
str1 = str1.Replace("this","xxxx");
```

Think about what's happening here.  str1 and str2 have a reference to the same string in the string pool.  str1.Replace() is not actually changing the existing string in the string pool(if it did, str1 AND str2 would have the new value), but rather it is creating a new string and then assigning str1 a reference to it.

Strings are immutable in the sense that, once they exist *in memory*, they cannot be changed.  The StringBuilder in C# allows us to avoid this problem.  We can freely modify what is in a StringBuilder object.  The string we create isn't commited to the string pool until we invoke the .ToString() method.

Comment: Actually, string literals are there when the program starts. When you create a new string, such as by calling `ToString` on an `int` or by using `StringBuilder`, then a new string is allocated. You may be thinking of `intern` ing.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the *references* to the string.  Those are indeed mutable.  Remember, strings are *reference types*.

That's why you can change string variable assignments.

However, actually trying to change the contents of the string is difficult, to say the least (it's *not* impossible, but for all intents and purposes, should be considered to be so).

This is why all the methods on strings which perform operations on the string (Trim, ToUpper, etc, etc) return *new* strings; the original one the method was called on is immutable.

Comment: When you say "difficult", you should say "only possible with explicit memory manipulation that violates the language and runtime expectations".

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** Correct, if that's not the desired functionality, look into a StringBuilder object.

**Question 2:** No, the clone returns a reference to the original string. Any modifications will be done to the memory referenced by the new pointer str2.

Comment: Q2: No, because you cannot modify the string (using standard .net string methods). See my answer for details (or try it, if you don't believe me ;-) ).