# Pass by copy or reference?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am a bit new to C# and was just wondering if there is a list of classes (commonly used) which are by default passed as copy.  How can I identify them?

I know the basic basic object types — int, uint, float, strings, ... — are passed by copy.

Comment: Thomas Levesque's answer answers the question. Just an additional note, when value types are copied, it is by default only a shallow copy - if a struct contains a reference type, the copy will point to the same reference object rather than cloning a new object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In C# / .Net objects can either be classified as value or reference types [1].  Value types are any type which derive from `System.ValueType` and are defined in C# with the `struct` type declaration.  These are passed by copy / value.

Reference types are types which do not derive from `System.ValueType` and are defined in C# with the `class` keyword.  Identifiers to instances of reference types are known as references (similar to pointers).  These are also passed by value by default but only the reference is passed not the whole object.

Your question also mentioned that `string` instances are passed by copy.  `String` in .Net is a reference type (derives directly from `System.Object`) and hence is not passed by full copy.

[1] Pointers may merit their own class here but I'm ignoring them for this discussion.

Comment: Thank you, the System.ValueType inheritance in between helped me understand this!

Answer (score 12):

All types, by default, are passed by value. The difference between *value types* (`struct`) and *reference types* (`class`) is that for value types a *copy* of the value is passed to the method, whereas for reference types, only a reference is passed.

[See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et.aspx) for more details.

Also, don't confuse the notion of value/reference types, and the notion of passing parameters by value or by reference. See [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) by Jon Skeet for details

Comment: No, both are passed by value.  In the case of references though it's the reference which is passed by value, not the object.

Comment: Indeed, that was badly phrased... I fixed it

Answer (score 4):

In general,

- *value types*, which includes native types (`int`,  `float`, ...) as well as `struct`s are passed "by copy" (as you put it), whereas in
- *reference types*, which includes `class`es, only a reference is copied instead of the complete object.

Note, though, that *string* is not passed "by copy"! It's a reference type, but since it's immutable, [it behaves similar to a value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449620).

Note that the `ref` keyword can be useful in both cases: In the case of value types, it means that the value is copied back. In the case of reference types, it means that the *reference* can be changed (i.e., that you can assign the variable to a new object rather than just changing the properties of the object.)

Comment: -1 all types are passed by value in c# unless you use the ref or out keywords.  It just happens that with reference types the value is the reference. e.g. if you pass a reference type into a method and set it to null in the method, if doesn't null out the variable you passed in only the COPY in the method.

Comment: @Ben: Exactly, that's why I avoided the phrase "by reference" in the second case and explicity mentioned the use of the ref keyword. I've reworded my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: removed my -1 becuase you updated your answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks (for removing the -1 as well as for the feedback).

Answer (score 3):

Note also that struct objects can include reference types:

```
struct Currency
{
    int Amount {get;set;} // is referenced by value (copy)
    string Code {get;set;} // is referenced by reference
}
```

When your use that struct like this:

```
var obj1 = new Currency{Amount = 1, Code = "USD"};
var obj2 = obj1;
```

Then

```
object.ReferenceEquals(obj1.Code, obj2.Code); // false - string is reference type, but used inside value type
```

If you have declared Currency as class then references to Code were the same.